# Using CLI to make Google Earth Engine asset public

Tags: google-earth-engine

I use the CLI to copy a shapefile from my google cloud storage bucket to an 'asset' in Google Earth Engine. This works no problem. And, I know that I can use the code editor directly to make the asset 'public' or allow access by an app.

I also know that there are CLI commands to set access to be public. But, when I try this:

earthengine acl set public users/dfh/ms_shapefile/csodata

I get the message that the 'asset does not exist or is not accessible.' Same for asset info, or other commands.

I have been looking here: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/command_line#acl

With no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it...needs to be a cloud asset, not legacy....